# Restricting client-side SSH configurations

Tags: ssh, permissions, ssh-tunneling

We allow a small group of student users to connect to our servers using `ssh` with local forwarding in order to access data science / programming resources such as Jupyter, rstudio, etc.

Recently I have noticed that students cannot keep track of which host they are in when they run `ssh`. As an example, a student will run `ssh -L foo:localhost:foo host1`, and then within `host1`, they run `ssh -L foo:localhost:foo hostN` to connect to `host1` or another of our hosts. This of course breaks port forwarding on `foo` for all other users, as now `host` is listening on `foo`.

Temporarily I have restricted `ssh` on the host so that students can't run the `ssh` client on the remote host. However, I can't completely rule out that a user doesn't need `ssh` access at some point.

Is there a way to configure (in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`,perhaps) client-side `ssh` to prevent users from launching hazardous commands? For instance, I would love to block listening on `foo` on `host1`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily control the client side but you can control the server side, defined in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Disable all the Forwarding options and restart the service:

```
DisableForwarding yes
```

Note that this removes the trivial approach with `ssh -L` or `ssh -R` but it doesn't stop someone setting up an application proxy (say, with `netcat` or `socat`).

Comment: Won't this prevent tunnelling from local machines to the server? I explicitly want to limit forwarding from particular servers, but still allow users to tunnel to those servers.

Comment: Oh I see, so you want to limit forwarding based on the _originating_ system? I don't think that's possible